# gnome-terminal Background color

Tags: fedora, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to setup different background colors based on the gnome-terminaltitle ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it in `xterm`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in `gnome-terminal`.

```
$ colr=blue
$ PS1="$PS1"'\[\e]0;[bash \v] \u@\h: \w\007\033]11;$colr\033\\\]'
$ colr=yellow
$ colr=black
```